# calling an asp.net function with jquery or ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, session

I am creationg an admin page, and I need to redirect the page after a few seconds if the user is not allowed to be there. there is supposed to be a session created when the admin has loged in, and i want to use jquery to check if the session exists.

here is the c# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((string)Session["admin"] == null)
    {
        mainF.InnerHtml = "<div id='inner' style='margin-left:370px; margin-top:80px;font: 0.92em arial,sans-serif;word-spacing: 2px;font-weight: bold;'>Your Are Not Supposed To Be Here.</div>";
    }
}
public bool checkIfAllowed()
{
    bool isIt = false;
    if ((string)Session["admin"] != null && (string)Session["admin"] != "")
    {
        isIt = true;
    }
    return isIt;
}
```

so basicly I thought that I can somehow use jquery to call the checkIfAllowed() function to check whether the session exists or not, but i dont know how.

this is what i have:

```
if (!checkIfAllowed() /*which of course doesn't work*/) {
        var inter = setInterval(function () {
            window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
        }, 3000);
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(inter);
    }
```

there probably are other ways to do this, if you have a some solution please tell me.
i guess i can also redirect the page with asp.net but it didn't work the first time.
i also tried writing

```
$("#inner").html != null && $("#inner").html != ""
```

in the if() statement in the jquery, because #inner html is changing on pageLoad in asp.net.

thanks =]

Comment: You cannot directly call a C# page function from JQuery. You will need to expose your method on a system accessible from HTTP, i.e. a web service, etc. You can then call the HTTP method from Jquery using the $.ajax method.

Comment: If not authenticated, a not admin user should not be allowed to enter the admin page at all. Check the user permission before he enters the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call your server-side method from your javascript, you have to register a script manager in your aspx page withe `EnablePageMethods` equals to true :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="MyScriptManager" 
    EnablePageMethods="true" 
    EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server" />
```

and to decorate your server-side method with the attribute `[WebMethod]` (namespace `System.Web.Services` :

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool checkIfAllowed()
{
    ...
}
```

and last thing in your javascript code you have to call the server-side method prefixed by the keyword `PageMethod` :

```
var isAllowed = PageMethods.checkIfAllowed();
```

---

**EDIT :**

As the call is asynchronous, the result of the function should be get in a callback function :

```
PageMethods.checkIfAllowed(function(response) {
    if (!response) {
        var inter = setInterval(function () {
            window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(inter);
    }
});
```

and also note that since your webmethod should be static, you have to use `HttpContext.Current.Session` instead of `Session`...

Comment: where in my aspx page do i put the scriptManager? (in the contectPlaceHolder..?)

Comment: Either in your master page or in the contentPlaceHolder. You can have a look to for example : http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx .

Comment: ok so not perfectly. the isAllowed var is allways undefind. =\

Comment: Hum, sorry, as it is asynchronous, you should get the result in the callback function. I have updated my post with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use ajax to call checkIfAllowed() google ajax tutorial

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

```
var session ='<%= Session("VariableName")%>'
if (!session) {
        var inter = setInterval(function () {
            window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
        }, 3000);
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(inter);
    }
```

Or you can use a HiddenField and load the data from your session and then just check if the value exists or not from javascript like

```
var hiddenValue = document.getElementById('myHiddenField');
if (!hiddenValue ) {
            var inter = setInterval(function () {
                window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
            }, 3000);
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(inter);
        }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: the var session ='<%= Session("VariableName")%>'
gives me an error saying Session doesn't exists in the current content

Comment: You can do the other way mentioned using a hiddenfield.